# JQuery - Is there any unclick event?

Tags: jquery

I have one principal checkbox to check automatically all the checkboxes from my html table.

And i used this code to do it:

```
   $('.checkallsave').click( function() {
        $('.savecheck').attr('checked',true);
    });
```

Now i want to uncheck all the checkboxes when the principal checkbox is unchecked too, how can i do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing what you really want is the `change` event, and check all the boxes based on the principal etc.

```
$('.checkallsave').on('change', function() {
     $('.savecheck').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/h8SsS/)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no uncheck event, but you can set the checked property of the savecheck checkboxes to match that of the checkallsave checkbox whenever you click it.

```
$('.checkallsave').click( function() {
    $('.savecheck').prop('checked',$(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cpra7/1)**

(little aside, here's a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/x6KQ5/) of the checkboxes that work both ways (changing the bottom boxes effects the main box), including the indeterminate property)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the current check box's condition, just edit the function code. Try this code:

```
$('.savecheck').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
```

This would check for the current (note the `this`) in the code. `this` would check for the condition of the `.checkallsave` element and then its condition would be applied to the `.savecheck` checkbox's too.